# Unable to resize Openstack instance

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

Within my Openstack deployment, I'm trying to resize an instance from large (4) to extra-large (5).

Horizon claims that it is scheduled, but nothing ever occurs. The machine's state doesn't seem to affect it. Also, it acts as if I never clicked the resize button. I assumed it was erroring out in the background.

Using `nova resize ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15 5`, it goes 100%, and claims that it's done, but on further examination after it doesn't get resized either.

In the log there is a 404 while trying to access the tenant_id, however it appears to continue on.  Since it doesn't work, logically the 404 error is likely the culprit. How can I troubleshoot this further?

This seems better suited for ask.openstack, but because it's part Juju, I figured I would start here.

**Debug Log**

```
bcollins@home:~/openstack$ nova --debug resize ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15 5
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v2token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v2:Token')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('admin_token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.admin_token:AdminToken')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3oidcauthcode = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:OpenIDConnectAuthorizationCode')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v2password = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v2:Password')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3password = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:Password')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3oidcpassword = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:OpenIDConnectPassword')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.generic:Token')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:Token')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('password = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.generic:Password')
DEBUG (session:248) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://10.14.0.58:5000/v2.0 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: keystoneauth1/2.5.0 python-requests/2.9.1 CPython/2.7.11"
INFO (connectionpool:207) Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.14.0.58
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "GET /v2.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 336
DEBUG (session:277) RESP: [200] Content-Length: 336 Vary: X-Auth-Token X-Distribution: Ubuntu Connection: keep-alive Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 12:24:53 GMT Content-Type: application/json X-Openstack-Request-Id: req-4344b594-afe0-4306-9a6b-9aafeca58e5c 
RESP BODY: {"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2014-04-17T00:00:00Z", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v2.0+json"}], "id": "v2.0", "links": [{"href": "http://10.14.0.58:5000/v2.0/", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://docs.openstack.org/", "type": "text/html", "rel": "describedby"}]}}

DEBUG (v2:63) Making authentication request to http://10.14.0.58:5000/v2.0/tokens
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "POST /v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1" 200 3421
DEBUG (session:248) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980 -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}baa89fb7b0707e1763dd5e760b5e865b3f6e0588"
INFO (connectionpool:207) Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.14.0.49
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "GET /v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980 HTTP/1.1" 404 52
DEBUG (session:277) RESP: [404] Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 12:24:53 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 52 X-Compute-Request-Id: req-4515f5c4-fd36-4051-bddc-fdf368e67f15 
RESP BODY: 404 Not Found

The resource could not be found.



DEBUG (session:248) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/ -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}baa89fb7b0707e1763dd5e760b5e865b3f6e0588"
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 375
DEBUG (session:277) RESP: [200] Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 12:24:53 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 375 X-Compute-Request-Id: req-07eaeb48-b820-41a2-ac12-5cd5e6868840 
RESP BODY: {"version": {"status": "SUPPORTED", "updated": "2011-01-21T11:33:21Z", "links": [{"href": "http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://docs.openstack.org/", "type": "text/html", "rel": "describedby"}], "min_version": "", "version": "", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.compute+json;version=2"}], "id": "v2.0"}}

DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v2token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v2:Token')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('admin_token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.admin_token:AdminToken')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3oidcauthcode = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:OpenIDConnectAuthorizationCode')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v2password = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v2:Password')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3password = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:Password')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3oidcpassword = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:OpenIDConnectPassword')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.generic:Token')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('v3token = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.v3:Token')
DEBUG (extension:157) found extension EntryPoint.parse('password = keystoneauth1.loading._plugins.identity.generic:Password')
DEBUG (session:248) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/servers/ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15 -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}baa89fb7b0707e1763dd5e760b5e865b3f6e0588"
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "GET /v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/servers/ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15 HTTP/1.1" 200 1575
DEBUG (session:277) RESP: [200] Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 12:24:54 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 1575 X-Compute-Request-Id: req-6deea0f6-a01d-4533-9998-0e1159773b32 
RESP BODY: {"server": {"status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2016-05-27T12:22:31Z", "hostId": "8f2be7edb99984916606b0d87e46aa6b3339aef6ed7a28fc91e3f273", "addresses": {"bcollins_net": [{"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:14:09:fc", "version": 4, "addr": "10.10.0.9", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"}, {"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:14:09:fc", "version": 4, "addr": "199.16.189.214", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "floating"}]}, "links": [{"href": "http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/servers/ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://10.14.0.49:8774/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/servers/ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15", "rel": "bookmark"}], "key_name": "Brian Mac-Book", "image": "", "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2016-05-24T12:23:10.000000", "flavor": {"id": "4", "links": [{"href": "http://10.14.0.49:8774/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/flavors/4", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15", "security_groups": [{"name": "Pelias"}], "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "region1-1", "user_id": "405f674382424cb5818502899b8a4d60", "name": "Pelias 01", "created": "2016-05-24T12:23:02Z", "tenant_id": "51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO", "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [{"id": "397964c9-4a58-4d7c-adab-03392ff02aff"}, {"id": "8517c1ce-16a7-4655-a88d-c184b5cc7926"}], "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, "config_drive": "", "metadata": {}}}

DEBUG (session:248) REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/flavors/5 -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}baa89fb7b0707e1763dd5e760b5e865b3f6e0588"
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "GET /v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/flavors/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 424
DEBUG (session:277) RESP: [200] Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 12:24:54 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 424 X-Compute-Request-Id: req-6a5723bb-4979-43b9-a096-dee17ecb497e 
RESP BODY: {"flavor": {"name": "m1.xlarge", "links": [{"href": "http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/flavors/5", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://10.14.0.49:8774/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/flavors/5", "rel": "bookmark"}], "ram": 16384, "OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled": false, "vcpus": 8, "swap": "", "os-flavor-access:is_public": true, "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 0, "disk": 160, "id": "5"}}

DEBUG (session:248) REQ: curl -g -i -X POST http://10.14.0.49:8774/v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/servers/ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15/action -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}baa89fb7b0707e1763dd5e760b5e865b3f6e0588" -d '{"resize": {"flavorRef": "5"}}'
DEBUG (connectionpool:387) "POST /v2/51a4655918f74a13a97b896fb841f980/servers/ee7dad49-cb71-4578-abc5-cf3b1225cb15/action HTTP/1.1" 202 0
DEBUG (session:277) RESP: [202] Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 12:24:54 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 0 X-Compute-Request-Id: req-e5954fd2-6f2d-4a3f-95db-a069fdd8b36d
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if we had the versions of the software you're using :)

Comment: I suppose it might, what specifically are you looking for?  Nova is running 3.4.0, Openstack is 2.3.0.  @Telegrapher